# Erlang. Registering processes assignment

Tags: process, parallel-processing, erlang

I am currently reading the Programming Erlang Second Edition Writing Software for a concurrent world written by Joe Armstrong and I have the following assignment :

> Write a function start(AnAtom, Fun) to register AnAtom as spawn(Fun). Make sure your program works correctly in the case when two parallel processes simultaneously evaluate start/2. In this case you must guarantee that one succeeds and the other fails.

I understand the first bit. I need to register the process of Fun to the AnAtom. However what does the second part want me to do?

If two processes call start/2 at the same time then one of them must fail? Why? Given that the AnAtom is different to any others (which will be done inside the body of start/2 why would I want to fail one of the processes?

From what I can understand so far we have:

```
a = spawn(process1).
b = spawn(process2).
a ! {self(), registerProcess} //which should call the start/2
b ! {self(), registerProcess} //which should call the start/2
```

What is the problem here? Two processes will evaluate start/2. Why fail one of them? I'm probably missing the logic here or what I understood so far is completely wrong. Can anybody explain this in easier terms so I can get my head around it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Check if parallel processes evaluate same function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22824234/check-if-parallel-processes-evaluate-same-function)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the exercise is asking you to think about what happens when two parallel process evaluate start/2 using the SAME atom as the first parameter. When start(a, MyFunction) completes, there should be a spawned function (running MyFunction) associated with the name (atom) a.... what happens if

```
start(cool, MyFun1) and
start(cool, MyFun2)
```

are both executed simultaneously? How do you guarantee that one succeeds and the other fails.... does this help?

EDIT:  I think you are not understanding the register process part of the assignment. When you get done with start(name, MyFun), doing a whereis(name) from the repl should return the process identifier of the process that got created.

This is not about sending the process a message to give it a name, it is about registering the process your created under the name passed in as the first parameter to start/2

Comment: Isn't this done automatically? I mean trying to register a second time with the same name should fail as the register(atom, PID) built-in function is already doing it

Comment: @Bula write down the steps of start/2... if two processes are making their way through start/2 in parallel than the steps you just wrote down could be executed in an interleaved fashion.... .... ... ... would that be bad... ... ..

Comment: Ahhh..  I think you are not understanding the register process part of the assignment. When you get done with start(name, MyFun), doing a whereis(name) from the repl should return in the process identifier of the process that got created.

Comment: I get the register process. Is my best bet then to simply queue the processes and then surround the register() with a try/catch? . However if they happen at the exact time then how do they get queued? (queue is using receive)

Comment: Steve's comment linking to possible duplicate question might shed some light?